# Code after the for loop is getting executed before the loop runs in node.js

Tags: node.js, promise

In the code below, I'm fetching data from an API end point by using `Promise.all()`. The results are mapped to the urls and I have to iterate over them in order to process the results. But the code after the loop keeps getting execute before the loop. How do I fix this?
Thank you.
Code:

```
con.collection("users").find(input).toArray((error,results) => {
        if(error){
            throw error;
        }
        if(!results.length){
            response.json({"msg":"user not found"});
        } else{

            //call google maps API to get address an make inverse index entry 

            //call gmaps API for each location

            //form urls
            urls = []
            locations.forEach(location => {
                lat = location.lat;
                long = location.long;
                urls.push( url+lat.toString()+","+long.toString()+"&key="+API_KEY)

            });
            console.log(urls);

            var locations_temp = []

            Promise.all(urls.map(url_ => 
                fetch(url_)
                    .then(checkStatus)
                    .then(parseJSON)
                    .catch(error => console.log("There was an error",error))
                ))
                .then(data => {
                    data.forEach((entry,index) => {
                        console.log(entry.results[0].formatted_address);
                        locations_temp.push(entry.results[0].formatted_address);
                    })
                });

            //this gets executed before the loop above. 
            console.log(locations_temp);
            console.log("here");
            console.log("locations:",locations_temp);
            //USER EXISTS, APPEND LOCATIONS 
            filter = {$push:{locations:{$each:locations_temp}}};
            con.collection("users").update(input,filter)
                .then(() => response.sendStatus(200))
                .catch((error) => {throw error});


        }
    });
};
```

Comment: if you want that to be executed after the fetch then you have to put it in the `.then` -- that is how promise works.  Why would expect it to wait?

Comment: First separate the array of promises from `Promise.all` a little bit to improve the readability of your code and it will help you spot the problem easier. Put the resolt of that map in a variable and make sure that it is an array that contains the promises.

Comment: The intermediate `.catch()` ... what is is supposed to achieve? It is seldom a good idea to catch an error simply to log it. If you want to inject a custom error message, then modify `error.message` and rethrow the error. If you want to inject a default object in place of missing data, then return (an instance of) your default object.

Comment: As written, `error` is caught and re-thrown into fresh air. If you are doing `response.sendStatus(200)` in the success path, then you should also be doing similar in the error path.